# Discarding a message in netty

Tags: java, netty

Does anyone know how a message could be discarded in Netty? By discard I mean that it would not be further forwarded on the channel to other handlers in the pipeline.

Is this the way that I can do it?

```
public class DiscardInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                                 Object msg) {
    ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
}
```

}

Comment: So... I've never used netty, but the very _first_ page of the [Getting Started tutorial](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html) demonstrates how to write a `DISCARD` server that ignores all received messages.  Is that not sufficient information for you to write what you need?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but thats the question, does the release() function prevent the msg to further travel through the pipeline of handlers?
In the link that you provided, only 1 handler is being used. What happens if we have more than 1 handlers?

Comment: You could try it and see what happens.  Willingness to learn by experimentation is a fundamental skill required of any software developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the responsibility of the user to call ReferenceCountUtil.release(message) if the message is 
consumed and not passed to the next ChannelOutboundHandler in the ChannelPipleline. Once the message is passed over to the actual Transport it will be released automatically by it once the message was written or the Channel was closed.

Source: Netty in Action book